# Regular Expression for strings with underscore

Tags: python, regex

I want to catch the following line in a parsed file using regex,

```
types == "EQUAL_NUM_SEQUENTIAL_LBAS":
```

for this, I am using the following code

```
variable = 'types'
for i in data:
    if re.search(re.escape(variable) + r"\s\=\=\s^[A-Z_]+$", i):
        print "yyy"
        break
```

where data here is the list of lines in the parsed file. What is wrong in the expression I have written?

Comment: Try removing the `^` and `$`

Comment: It would seem you want `\"` instead of `^`

Comment: You also need to replace `$` with `\":$`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a string consisting only of uppercase letters possibly separated by underscores, then use:

```
^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$
```

Sample script:

```
inp = "EQUAL_NUM_SEQUENTIAL_LBAS"
if re.search(r'^[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*$', inp):
    print "MATCH"
```

The regex pattern, read out loud and in order, says to match some capital letter only word, followed optionally by an underscore and another word, zero or more times.

To capture such words appearing anywhere in a larger text/document, use:

```
inp = "Here is one ABC_DEF word and another EQUAL_NUM_SEQUENTIAL_LBAS here"
words = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)*\b', inp)
print(words)
```

This prints:

```
['EQUAL_NUM_SEQUENTIAL', 'LBAS']
```

Comment: Just the string is working, But when I try to catch the whole line, Its not working

Comment: I have updated my answer with an option for finding these words in a larger text.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ^ charector in the pattern

```
 r"\s\s\=\=\s[A-Z_]+$"
```